# Why error was not shown when i tried to assign a value in the reserved words float and int?

Tags: python

In the book the question was given to find out the errors in the given statements in Python program. One of the statement was shown below

```
float = 1.75E9
```

But when i execute it is not showing error. As it is a reserved words, it should show error when i try to execute these statements. Also the following statement is also not showing error:

```
int =89 #some number
```

But after executing this, when i tries to show the equivalent value for the Boolean literals it shows me the following error :

```
**>>> int = 89
>>> int(True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    int(True)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>>**
```

Comment: You did not tried the equivalent with Boolean literals, you tried to call `int` with the parameter `True`. Try `int = True` instead, it will work without error.

Answer (score 2):

Because `int` and `float` are *not* reserved words.  They are built-in types, which are treated just like user-defined types.  And just like user-defined types, you are allowed to reassign them in case you need to patch things or change implementations on-the-fly.

Python's general philosophy is flexibility.  In this case you didn't mean to shadow the `int` and `float` types, but maybe there are some cases where you *would* want to do that.  In those cases, Python doesn't try to stop you (even though it would almost certainly be a bad idea to try to replace those types).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that int and float aren't reserved keywords in python like global, assert, yield etc are

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_keywords.asp

Answer (score 0):

The first two assign the values `1.75E9` and `89` to the variables `ìnt` and `float` respectively. These are, however, built-in names, so you are now saying that `int` will always refer to that variable, instead of an integer.

As a result, `int(True)` will try to do `89(True)`, which you can't, as that doesn't make any sense (89 is not the name of a method/class/...).

It's generally not recommended to use names like `int` and `float` for this purpose. You *can* do it if you want to, but you should just give them another name in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There's almost no limit to what variable name you can use in python. The language does not have any private attribute, protected class.

The following snippets will throw an error in python3..

```
>>True = 20
SyntaxError: cannot assign to True
>>False = []
SyntaxError: cannot assign to False
>>None = True
SyntaxError: cannot assign to None
```